# Enable javascript in Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website that has some server-side and some client-side rendering. Unfortunately, with the current setup the result I get back looks exactly the same as if I load the page in the browser after disabling JavaScript. Any idea how I can enable JavaScript in nightmare.js?

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: true
});

nightmare
    .goto('https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/celonis')
    .scrollTo(10,10)
    .wait(5000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        return {          
            'website': document.querySelectorAll('.icon_and_value li')[4].querySelector('label-with-icon span a').href,
            'img_url': document.querySelector('identifier-image').innerHTML
        }
    })
    .end()
    .then(function(dict) {
        console.log(dict)
    })
```